# New-Object -Type Microsoft.GroupPolicy.GPDomain fails when run remotely

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to run a script remotely (via vRO - essentially WinRM invoke), and am running into an issue with getting some commands to run.

I have two DCs: PRIDC and SECDC.

The command I'm having issues with:

```
$gpDomain = New-Object -Type Microsoft.GroupPolicy.GPDomain
```

It works when run manually on either server, or when run remotely against PRIDC.  Either way, it shows PRIDC as being the domain controller.
When run remotely against SECDC, I get the following error:

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "An operations error occured. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072020)"
```

I suspect that this is due to Powershell's "double-hop" problem.

The main use of this is to get WMI filters via $gpDomain.GetWmiFilter($path)

Is there any way to force the initial query to be against SECDC, or another way to get the WmiFilter object without running into the double-hop problem?

Comment: How are you running the command? What user are you running the commands under and do they have the correct permissions?

Comment: So are you adding it as a PowerShell host on vRO and then executing it against that host? If you are, then you won't run into the Double Hop problem. You will have double hop problem if you are adding a jump server as PS host on vRO and then going to the DCs from there.

Comment: Can you post the code how you're invoking the command remotely, maybe its a problem regarding [remote variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-6).

Comment: @RohinSidharth: Correct.  I did run into the double-hop problem with all the Get-AD* functions, but managed to remove them from the script (or replacing them with other functions)

Comment: @Moerwald: This is the code in vRO.
    var sess = pshost.openSession();
    var script = "&{cmd /c \"C:\\admin\\scripts\\Create Forest\\ContinueAddAnotherDC.cmd\"} *>>C:\\admin\\logs\\vRO.log";
    var result = sess.invokeScript(script);

The cmd then calls a ps1 via:
    powershell.exe -command .\script.ps1

However, in testing, I was just running the command in a remote pssession